# Problemas entre loop e ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax

**Ajax**

```
for (j=0; j < cidade_nome.length; j++) {
    $.post('envia.php', {ano:ano, ano2:ano2, cidade: cidade_nome[j].value}, fnRetorno);
}
```

**Função fnRetorno**

```
function fnRetorno(retorno) 
{
    teste.push(retorno);
    console.log(j);
    if (j == cidade_nome.length) {
        soma(teste);
    }
}
```

**Código Completo**

```
function soma(teste) 
{
    console.log(JSON.parse(teste));
}

function fnRetorno(retorno) 
{
    teste.push(retorno);
    console.log(j);
    if (j==cidade_nome.length) {
        soma(teste);
    }
}

for (j=0;j<cidade_nome.length;j++) {
    $.post('envia.php', {ano: ano, ano2: ano2, cidade: cidade_nome[j].value}, fnRetorno);
}
```

Pelo ajax ser assíncrono, a função `fnRetorno` chama a função soma, antes do último resultado do ajax ser colocado no array `teste`.

Teria alguma forma de garantir que a função teste soma só seria chamado após o ajax ser executado todas as vezes pelo loop?

Comment: Desculpe, mas você quer que ele chame APÓS executar TODAS as vezes ou seja... uma vez, ou a CADA VEZ que ele terminar de executar a requisição?

Comment: Que ele chame a função soma,apenas uma vez.Acho que não deixei claro,perdão

Comment: Explique melhor o que pretende fazer com a requisição. O que o servidor faz? Qual o retorno?

Comment: A requisição retorna para a função fnRetorno um JSON que deve ser colocado no array,para na função Soma ser gerado um gráfico.

Comment: Mas qual o motivo de executar esta requisição em um loop? Você não pode simplesmente passar todo o array de uma vez e executar o laço no servidor? Por exemplo: `$.post('envia.php',{ano:ano,ano2:ano2,cidades:cidade_nome}, fnRetorno);`

Comment: Então você pode chamar o soma uma única vez após o for (e retirar ele do fnRetorno) e tratar seu array usando $.each como você precisa, não é isso? @Oeslei, sua indicação também é bastante interessante.

Comment: @RafaelWithoeft Isso não é possível com uma requisição assíncrona. A função seria executada antes do retorno do servidor.

Comment: @Oeslei Opa, desculpe o deslize não lembrei desse detalhe, bom só vejo duas saídas, mudar o ajax para síncrono ou mandar a lógica para o servidor;

Comment: A idéia do @Oeslei funcionaria,mas o meu cidade_nome vem de:"var cidade_nome = $('#cidade option:selected');",eu precisaria transformar em um array mesmo correto?

Comment: @RodolfoOliveira Você está executando um loop para percorrer uma string? Por quê?

Comment: @Oeslei não é uma string,estou usando um 'componente' que é um combo de checkbox,e cidade_nome recebe um objeto com as opções selecionadas

Comment: @RodolfoOliveira, você pode então usar algo como $.each para percorrer seus valores formando um array e então mandar para o servidor, ou trocar seu componente e deixar o jquery cuidar disso para você exemplo: `var cidades = []; //Percorre tudo o que está selecionado em cidades $('#cidades :checked').each(function(i) { 
  cidades[i] = $(this).val(); 
});`

Answer (score 1):

No seu caso, dá pra fazer uma coisa bem mais simples do que você está fazendo, e evitaria tantos posts desnecessários, algo do tipo:

```
function soma(teste) 
{
    console.log(JSON.parse(teste));
}

function fnTest(data, pos) 
{
    teste.push(data, pos);
    if (pos==cidade_nome.length) {
        soma(teste);
    }
}

var data_post = {};
    for (var i in cidade_nome) {
         data_post[i] = {ano: ano, ano2: ano2, cidade: cidade:cidade_nome[i].value};
           fnTest(data_post[i], i);
        } 

    $.post('envia.php',data:data_post, function(rtn) {
          console.log(JSON.parse(rtn));
     });
```

E no PHP você faz a tratativa que precisa:

```
<?php
//captura a saída e veja o que retorna para fazer a tratativa 
var_dump($_POST['data']);
exit;
```

Answer (score 0):

Creio que a abordagem mais correta no seu caso seria:

```
function fnRetorno(j) {

    if (j >= cidade_nome.length) return;

    $.post('envia.php', {..., cidade: cidade_nome[j].value}, function ()
    {
        // Não sei de onde vem a variável 'teste'
        soma(teste);

        fnRetorno(++j);
    })

};

fnRetorno(0);
```

Pois nesse caso, você vai chamar a próxima chamada ajax apenas quando a anterior for encerrada.

Perceba que o `j` foi passado por parâmetro. Isso ajuda a diminuir a poluição do escopo do seu código, além de fazer exatamente a mesma coisa desejada no `for`, que é ele iterar até que haja o elemento equivalemente em `cidade_nome`.

Answer (score 0):

Bom dia Rodolfo tente dessa maneira:

```
$.ajax({
    //função ajax
}).done(function () {
    //função após o ajax
});
```

Essa é uma outra maneira, onde você garante uma chamada após o retorno do ajax